# Trouble transferring variables between structs/content views SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a muffin clicker game for iOS, and am trouble transferring information from the main screen where you can click the muffin, to the shop screen where you can buy upgrades. I am using "@Binding" to do this. There is a button that I have as a placeholder that changes the screen to the the shop menu, and sets all of the variables in the new screen to the variables in the old screen. I am getting an error that says: "Result of 'Shop' initializer is unused", and when I press the button nothing helps.

Button Code:

```
Button("Placeholder") {Shop(muffins : $muffins , worth : $worth , worthuc : $worthuc , muffinsps : $muffinsps , muffinspsuc : $muffinspsuc)}
```

Code for variables in shop struct

```
struct Shop: View {
    @Binding var muffins: Int
    @Binding var worth: Int
    @Binding var worthuc: Int
    @Binding var muffinsps: Int
    @Binding var muffinspsuc: Int
```

[Image of Xcode Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVueQ.png)

I have looked for related videos/questions but have, been unable to find anything.

Comment: So you want the button to show the `Shop` view? How about using a `NavigationLink` instead?

Comment: Did you search for that error on SO? The action of a Button isn’t a ViewBuilder. I’m sure you are getting a message that the line is unused.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shop is a View and thus when just put into the action part of a button doesn't trigger any action because shop itself doesn't perfome any changes. Your problem basically comes down to not switching between views correctly. Here is a guide to how to switch between views with the Navigation framework: https://medium.com/codex/how-to-navigate-between-views-in-swift-ui-46cf62ef6df5 For your usecase a popup view might be an option as well. More info to that can be found here. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-show-a-popover-view.